# Dockerizing Nodejs dependencies for Gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using Gitlab CI in order to implement CI for my Node.js app. I'm already using artifacts and sharing the dependencies between jobs, however, I would like to make it faster. Every time a pipeline starts, it installs the dependencies during the first job and I'm thinking to prevent this by having all dependencies in a Docker image and pass that image to test & production stages. However, I have been unable to do so. Apparently Gitlab doesn't run the code inside my image's WORKDIR.

Following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.13-alpine
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
CMD [“sh”]
```

And following is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
test:
  image: azarboon/dependencies-test
  stage: test
  script:
     — pwd
     — npm run test
```

Looking at logs, `pwd` results in `/builds/anderson-martin/lambda-test`, which is different from the defined WORKDIR and also installed dependencies are not found. Do you have any recommendation for me how can I Dockerize my dependencies and speed up the build stage?

Comment: Have you tried docker's multi-stage builds? See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: yes tired multi-stage build and copy your dependency from parent image

Comment: we implement the same scenario but for that we local npm registry which install npm module every time from local registry but that is faster than installing from the remote registry and we install during boot time

Comment: @Yuankun thank you. I will read that article thoroughly, but do you have any idea for Gitlab CI? How can I refer to my node_modules, inside Docker image, while I'm in test stage of Gitlab?

Comment: @Mahdi Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to solve your issue is to symlink the node_modules folder from your base image into the gitlab CI workspace like this:

```
test:
  image: azarboon/dependencies-test
  stage: test
  script:
     — ln -s /home/app/node_modules ./node_modules
     — npm run test
```

The syntax for symlinking is `ln -s EXISTING_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY SYMLINK_NAME`.

Please note that `/home/app/` is the workspace which you´re using in your base image.

Gitlab also provides other functionality to share dependencies. On the one hand you have [caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) and on the other [job artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html).